# The resource path has been normalized to [null]

Tags: java, xml, apache, servlets

I'm trying to make servlet, that parses the xml and print information from it.

Here is the part my code:

```
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException  {

    List<Inventory> list = null;
    DOMParser domParser = new DOMParser();
    pw = res.getWriter();
    try {
        list = domParser.parse(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("../SportInventory.xml"));
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
        return;
    }
    pw.println("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>title</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>");
    pw.println("<p>done</p>");
    pw.println("</BODY></HTML>");
    pw.close();
}
```

Here is directories structure:
[https://imgur.com/4bmwdMC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doMSW.png)

schemaLocation in my xml:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://nure.ua/sportInventory sportInventory.xsd"
```

As a result I have next:
[https://imgur.com/sCzSxFc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYmKd.png)

Previously thx for helping and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
list = domParser.parse(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/SportInventory.xml"))
```

File location must start with "/".

Comment: Try my edited solution. I remove ".." from path. When its not work please check if xml file exists in your jar/war file. Xml file shoud be in root directory in jar.

Comment: Now it throws SAXParseException. Looks like the topic issue was solved so thx a lot :)